# refer a section in a method

Tags: cocoa-touch, uitableview

I'm doing surveys like project in which questions and answers are displayed. I'm displaying them in `tableView` with labels and buttons. But Now I am not getting how to handle each answer selected.

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
 NSMutableArray *sectionItems=[self.finalarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
    int n=[sectionItems count];

    NSString *question = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[sectionItems  objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Question"]];
    CGSize constraint1 = CGSizeMake(320, 2000.0f);
    CGSize size1 = [question sizeWithFont: [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:14] constrainedToSize:constraint1 lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
    lblQuestion = (UILabel *)[hlcell viewWithTag:1];
    lblQuestion.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",question];

    lblQuestion. numberOfLines=0;
    lblQuestion.frame = CGRectMake(10,15, size1.width, size1.height);

 UIButton *btTemp1 = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, lblQuestion.frame.origin.y+lblQuestion.frame.size.height,10, 15)];
        [btTemp1 addTarget:self action:@selector(radioButtonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        btTemp1.contentHorizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentLeft;
        [btTemp1 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"radio_button_off.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [btTemp1 setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        btTemp1.titleLabel.font =[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.f];
        [hlcell.contentView addSubview:btTemp1];



        NSLog(@"%@",[[sectionItems  objectAtIndex:1] objectForKey:@"Description"]);
        NSString *option1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[sectionItems  objectAtIndex:1] objectForKey:@"Description"]];
        CGSize constraint2 = CGSizeMake(320, 2000.0f);
        CGSize size2 = [option1 sizeWithFont: [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:14] constrainedToSize:constraint2 lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
        lblOption1 = (UILabel *)[hlcell viewWithTag:1];
        lblOption1.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",option1];
        [lblOption1 setNumberOfLines:0];
        lblOption1.frame = CGRectMake(30,lblQuestion.frame.origin.y+lblQuestion.frame.size.height, size2.width, size2.height);
        [hlcell.contentView addSubview:lblanswers];

        UIButton *btTemp2 = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, lblOption1.frame.origin.y+lblOption1.frame.size.height,10, 15)];
        [btTemp2 addTarget:self action:@selector(radioButtonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        btTemp2.contentHorizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentLeft;
        [btTemp2 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"radio_button_off.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [btTemp2 setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        btTemp2.titleLabel.font =[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.f];
        [hlcell.contentView addSubview:btTemp2];



        NSString *option2 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[sectionItems  objectAtIndex:2] objectForKey:@"Description"]];
        CGSize constraint3 = CGSizeMake(320, 2000.0f);
        CGSize size3 = [option2 sizeWithFont: [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:14] constrainedToSize:constraint3 lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
        lblOption2 = (UILabel *)[hlcell viewWithTag:2];
        lblOption2.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",option2];
        [lblOption2 setNumberOfLines:0];
        lblOption2.frame = CGRectMake(30,lblOption1.frame.origin.y+lblOption1.frame.size.height, size3.width, size3.height);
        [hlcell.contentView addSubview:lblOption2];

return hlcell;
}
```

I have 10 questions and how can I get the answer selected in each section and store it.
I am unable to refer indexpath. Section in `radioButtonClicked` method. And if I select a `radiobutton` in one section it is enabled and others are disabled. But if I check `radiobutton` in other section all the `radiobuttons` prevoiusly checked are also disabled. How can I handle radiobutton selection for a section separately.

Answer (score 0):

Store clicked indexPath in a dictionary and manage cell display according to selected values. By setting them selected while creating them in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, according to stored values. Like:

```
if([[selectedRows valueForKey:stringRepresentationOfIndexPath] boolValue] == YES)
  [btTemp1 setSelected:YES];
```

**Edit:** `selectedRows` is dictionary that contains data of rows that are selected, update it in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`, or on but click (if you are doing it like that).

Comment: Sorry I didn't get u.Where should I write this ?And what is selectedRows?

Comment: Check edit, and write it in `cellForRowAtIndexPath ` as i mentioned